# Excel 2010 vlookup formula - Using variable table array as input

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I have been trying to find out if its possible to automatically expand the table_array on this `VLOOKUP` formula:

`=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$F$4:$G$965,2,FALSE)`

I'm calling the values from Sheet2 to add into a new dataset in Sheet3, however, the number of rows  in Sheet2 can vary so I want the formula to recognize those extra rows when added. I tried using `COLUMN(G:G)` as third argument but for some reason it doesn't look for that column on 'Sheet2' and it results in error.

Thanks

Comment: I usually name the table_array and use the name rather than `sheet!R1C1` format.  Once that's done you can simply update the name in Name Manager making 1 change to update all the formulas.

Comment: @Tyson Better yet, define the named range dynamically and you'll have to do no updating of anything.

Comment: @Excellll thanks! I tried that once long ago and never got it to work for me. I just now [googled](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287) and remembered the previous experiments.  Now that I have more experience I'm going to try again =]

Answer (score 2):

If you can determine the range (i.e., determine the last row of the range)
that you want to search, you can use the `INDIRECT()` function to address it. 
For example, if you can get `Sheet2!$F$4:$G$965` into cell `Z1`, then you can say

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, INDIRECT(Z1), 2, FALSE)
```

You might be able to determine the range with a function like `COUNTA()`. 
For example,

```
COUNTA(Sheet2!$G:$G)
```

counts the cells in column `Sheet2!G` that are not empty.

P.S. I’m not sure whether there’s any benefit to using `$` signs in references to other sheets.